# How to create UDP socket connection to receive data from gstreamer udpsink?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, gstreamer

I want to create a UDP socket connection to receive data from GStreamer udpsink. When I create a Gstreamer pipeline using udpsink, VLC can play the stream. I want to create my own  program that would receive udp packets from Gstreamer udpsink. The UDP connection code I wrote just waits on recvfrom method. Can you please help?

```
    // Creating socket file descriptor
if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
    perror("socket creation failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
   
// Filling server information
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
   
int n, len;
int loop = 10;
do
{
       
n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE, 
            MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
            &len);
buffer[n] = '\0';
printf("Server : %s\n", buffer);
} while (--loop);
close(sockfd);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misisng the call to `bind`, so that you listen on the specific address/port:

```
// Bind the socket with the server address 
if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,  
        sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 ) 
{ 
    perror("bind failed"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
```

In the call to `recvfrom`, `servaddr` is filled with the remote address, it is an output argument. In your current code, the server information is not used.